# How can I reset blender from ) again?

Tags: image

I was taking a course and meanwhile I was following along the course the guy was deleting some stuff in preferences on the keymap. I don't know what I delete that I can't move the object with the <kbd>G</kbd> anymore.

Also, all the other keys are not working (<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd>, and all of them) I was trying to delete blender again so to start all over again, but every time I downloaded the problem doesn't go away.

How can I have Blender reset from 0 again when you downloaded for the first time?

Answer (score 0):

File > Defaults > Load Factory Settings

To make it permanent you also need to press ''Save Startup File'' and ''Save Preferences''

Edit > Preferences > Save Preferences (Bottom left corner)

[image]

[image]